# Probability of drawing at least one card from each suit

Tags: probability

Suppose you have a deck of 16 cards, 4 from each suit.  You shuffle them and deal out eight cards face up.  What is the probability that you will have at least one card from each suit showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C(n,k)$ be the binomial coefficient, then the probability of a particular suit NOT appearing is
$$\frac{{C(16 - 4,8)}}{{C(16,8)}}.$$
Similarly, the probability of two suits NOT appearing is
$$\frac{{C(16 - 8,8)}}{{C(16,8)}}$$
and the probability of three suits NOT appearing is
$$\frac{{C(16 - 12,8)}}{{C(16,8)}}$$
and the probability of four suits not appearing is
$$\frac{{C(16 - 16,8)}}{{C(16,8)}} = 0.$$
Therefore, the probability that at least one of the suits does NOT appear is
$$\frac{{4C(16 - 4,8) - 6C(16 - 8,8) + 4C(16 - 12,8)}}{{C(16,8)}}$$
so
$$1 - \frac{{4C(16 - 4,8) - 6C(16 - 8,8) + 4C(16 - 12,8)}}{{C(16,8)}}$$
is the probability we seek (4,-6, and 4 come from [the inclusion-exclusion principle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inclusion-ExclusionPrinciple.html)). Watch this YouTube [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8mOws755Bs) if you do not understand the inclusion-exclusion principle.